# What is eigenvalue decay?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've come across the term "eigenvalue decay" in several machine learning papers recently, but I do not know what it means. I also haven't managed to find a definition online.

> We are interested in the exact structure of the eigenvalues of the kernel matrix. In particular, we want to explain the experimental findings that the eigenvalues decay as quickly as their asymptotic counterparts.

This relates to kernel-based methods.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925231213008333

Comment: When you quote someone, you should mention where the quote comes from

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same question and found the answer in this case to be the decay rate of the eigenvalues (sorted in decreasing order) for the kernel matrix.

Reference: Definition 13 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03708.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1930669)